# Twine is asking for my password each time : how to use the .pypirc

Tags: python, setuptools, twine

I have `pip` installed `pypirc` and set up a `~/.pypirc` file with the requisite password.  Why is `twine` asking for a password each time `python setup.py` is invoked?

```
  $twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
  Enter your username:
```

Here is the form of the `.pypirc`

```
[distutils] # this tells distutils what package indexes you can push to
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: myuser 
password: mypwd 

[pypitest]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: myuser 
password: mypwd
```

**Update** Not including the `--repository-url` gives:

```
UploadToDeprecatedPyPIDetected: You're trying to upload to the legacy PyPI site 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi'. Uploading to those sites is deprecated.
 The new sites are pypi.org and test.pypi.org. Try using https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ (or https://test.pypi.org/legacy/) to upload your packages instead. These are the default URLs for Twine now.
 More at https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/ .
```

Comment: How could we guess without looking at your `~/.pypirc`? Also to use `~/.pypirc` you should pass `--repository name`, not `--repository-url url`.

Comment: @phd  The references to `twine` that I had found used the form above: `--repository-url <url>` and not `--repository name` . I do not have an example for the latter.

Comment: @phd The `twine` docs support the format included in the question: https://pypi.org/project/twine/  Can you provide info and/or reference on why a different format is preferred?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. `-r <name>`. AFAIU `twine --repository-url <url>` doesn't even consult `~/.pypirc`. With `-r <name>` it lookups `~/.pypirc` for the URL, user name and password. If you omit `-r <name>`, `twine` uses the first repo from `~/.pypirc`.

Comment: The warning is because you've got the old URLs in `.pypirc`. Do what it says.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
twine upload dist/*
```

or

```
twine upload -r pypi dist/*
```

or

```
twine upload -r pypitest dist/*
```

As far as I understand `twine --repository-url <url>` doesn't even consult `~/.pypirc`. With `-r <name>` it lookups `~/.pypirc` for the URL, user name and password. If you omit `-r <name>`, twine uses the first repo from `~/.pypirc`.

Comment: I tried the first one multiple times and it does not work.  I have not tried the `-r` yet: will lyk.

Comment: `UploadToDeprecatedPyPIDetected: You're trying to upload to the legacy PyPI site 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi'. Uploading to those sites is deprecated.
 The new sites are pypi.org and test.pypi.org. Try using https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ (or https://test.pypi.org/legacy/) to upload your packages instead. These are the default URLs for Twine now.
 More at https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/ .`

Comment: In `~/.pypirc`: `repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/` or `repository: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`.

Comment: ah ok.  as you mentioned i should have included contents of `/.pypirc`

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1:

```
python -m twine upload  dist/* -u%username% -p%password%
```

you can

```
set username="__token__"

set password="pypi-AgEIc..."
```

#### OR

```
set username=pypi name

set password=pypi password
```

Comment: The question asks how to use `.pypirc`, so this is not really a valid answer, but an alternative approach.